# Is a falling tree, a tree that has fallen? What is "falling" if it is not an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, gerunds, parts-of-speech

Headline in *[The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/08/09/us/soldiers-killled-georgia-weather.html)*:

> **Falling Tree Kills 2 Soldiers During Storm in Georgia**
> Two U.S. Army soldiers were struck by a falling tree and killed on Tuesday while
> sheltering near Yonah Mountain in northern Georgia, where they had
> been training before a severe thunderstorm blasted the area with
> strong winds, Army officials said.

I get from that the tree has already fallen, as I'm learning English, so I guess falling is not an adjective right? What is it then?

Comment: [Falling](https://www.lexico.com/definition/falling) is an adjective. The tree fell on the soldiers and killed them. That dictionary reference actually gives the example *she was injured by a falling tree*.

Answer (score 2):

"Falling" is a participle used as an adjective.

The tree has already fallen, and it has already killed two soldiers, presumably by falling on them.  Therefore, it was while it was falling that it killed them.